# Is SSL certificate is need for implementing Azure authentication/Authorization to the Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have developed the asp.net MVC web app with work or school account authentication mode. The created code base is moved to azure app service and the same code is working fine in local but not in azure app service. So I suspect is this is the problem due to not adding SSL certification to the website.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: When you say not working what does that mean? How do you suspect that it could be SSL certificate issue?

Comment: The we app is running locally when I run from Visual studio but the same code is not working when I run after hosting to the Azure app services.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The we app is running locally when I run from Visual studio but the same code is not working when I run after hosting to the Azure app services. I saw in some of the articles says that some OAuth providers need SSL certificate.

Comment: What does it mean "Not working"?

Comment: When moving the app from one URL to another, remember to update the login redirect URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL certificate may be needed for most OAuth providers, but **it is provided by Azure itself automatically** (unless you host your app on a custom domain). You problem must be something different.

Comment: @TamilselvanSellappan What was the actual solution?

Comment: It depends on what error you get.. I.e. what does "not working" mean (website is not showing something, not starting, not working as expected, not logging users in?)